# In JetBrains Rider, how can I show type information for the symbol under the cursor?

Tags: f#, jetbrains-ide, rider

Specifically, for F# in Visual Studio, I often use the Quick Info (Edit.QuickInfo) keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl+K, Ctrl+I</kbd>) to show type information for the symbol under the cursor:

[image: Visual Studio Quick Info tooltip]

Is there a keyboard shortcut that does this in JetBrains Rider?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but the action is confusingly called "Error Description" (<kbd>Ctrl+F1</kbd>) in Rider:

[image: Rider Keymap showing Error Description action]

Unfortunately, it isn't syntax-highlighted:

[image: Rider Error Description tooltip]